# FTextField, Jlabel and more mistakes in converter java program

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

When I go to try to run my temperature converter program, I find these errors, does anyone know what is missing?

The code is giving these errors of the image, Jlabel, FtextField and maybe something is missing, is it?

Do you have something to do in this case?

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccte7.jpg)

Main.java

```
package swing;

public class main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConversorTemperatura ct = new ConversorTemperatura();
        ct.exibir();
    }

}
```

ConversorTemperatura.java

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ConversorTemperatura {
    private JFrame frmJanela;
    private FTextField txtFah;
    private JLabel lblFah;
    private JButton btnConverter;
    private Jlabel lblCelsius;
    
    public void exibir() {
        frmJanela.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public ConversorTemperatura() {
        frmJanela = new JFrame();
        frmJanela.setTitle("Conversor Fahrenheit p/ Celsius");
        frmJanela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmJanela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder (10,10,10,10));
        frmJanela.setContentPane(p);
        
        
        1.setHgap(10);
        1.setVgap(10);
        frmJanela.setLayout(1);
        
        frmJanela.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        
        txtFah = new JTextField();
        txtFah.setColumns(5);
        frmJanela.add(txtFah);
        
        lblFah = new JLabel();
        lblFah.setText("Fahrenheit");
        frmJanela.add(lblFah);
        
        btnConverter = new JButton();
        btnConverter.setText("Converter");
        frmJanela.add(btnConverter);
        
        lblCelsius = new JLabel();
        lblCelsius.setText("Celsius");
        frmJanela.add(lblCelsius);
        
        frmJanela.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Variables can't start with numbers

Comment: In this case? "1.setHgap(10);" What should I do?

Comment: 1) Don't post images of text. post the text itself. 2) Don't bother trying to run code before it compiles cleanly. 3) Solve each compilation error as soon as the IDE flags it.

Comment: Sorry, but could you help-me?

Comment: `FTextField` should be `JTextField`. You want to set the `GridLayout` to the panel (`p`) and add components to it. Not to the `JFrame`.  These lines of code `1.setHgap(10);
  1.setVgap(10);   frmJanela.setLayout(1)` are not valid in Java.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I got it and understood what is most important.

Answer (score 1):

[Learning the Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) might be a better place to start

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ConversorTemperatura {

    private JFrame frmJanela;
    private JTextField txtFah;
    private JLabel lblFah;
    private JButton btnConverter;
    private JLabel lblCelsius;

    public void exibir() {
        frmJanela.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ConversorTemperatura() {
        frmJanela = new JFrame();
        frmJanela.setTitle("Conversor Fahrenheit p/ Celsius");
        frmJanela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmJanela.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        frmJanela.setContentPane(p);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 2);
        layout.setHgap(10);
        layout.setVgap(10);
        frmJanela.setLayout(layout);

        //frmJanela.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        txtFah = new JTextField();
        txtFah.setColumns(5);
        frmJanela.add(txtFah);

        lblFah = new JLabel();
        lblFah.setText("Fahrenheit");
        frmJanela.add(lblFah);

        btnConverter = new JButton();
        btnConverter.setText("Converter");
        frmJanela.add(btnConverter);

        lblCelsius = new JLabel();
        lblCelsius.setText("Celsius");
        frmJanela.add(lblCelsius);

        frmJanela.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend. I'll look at the link you sent me to learn better, thanks so much for the advice.